# mysql client prints help message when run with script, but runs fine directly in shell

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, scripting

I am having a weird shell script issue. I am trying to run a `mysql` command from the shell either against a local docker instance, or via ssh against a database that is not publicly accessible. I have this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# 0: Check DB status
# 1: Query MySql for latest migration
# 2: Check sql dir for migrations newer than query result
# 3..: Execute newer sql *in order*
 
################################################################################
# script and sql calls
################################################################################

DB_HOST=$1
DB_USER=$2
DB_PASSWORD=$3
DB_NAME=$4

if [[ -z $REMOTE_HOST ]]; then
    SSH_PREFIX=""
else
    SSH_PREFIX="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i sshkey ${REMOTE_USER}@${REMOTE_HOST}"
fi

MYSQL_CLIENT="mysql --protocol=tcp -h ${DB_HOST} -u ${DB_USER} --password=${DB_PASSWORD}"

#checking mysql connection
mysql_db_statuscheck(){
    echo "`date` :Checking DB connectivity...";
    echo "`date` :Trying to connect to the ODU MySQL Database..."
    EXEC_SQL="-e 'SELECT 1;'"
    cmd="${SSH_PREFIX} ${MYSQL_CLIENT} ${EXEC_SQL} ${DB_NAME}"
    echo $cmd
    $cmd
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
    then
        DB_STATUS="UP"
        export DB_STATUS
        echo "`date` :Status: ${DB_STATUS}. Able to Connect..."
    else
        DB_STATUS="DOWN"
        export DB_STATUS
        echo "`date` :Status: DOWN . Not able to Connect."
        echo "`date`:Not able to connect to database with Username:
        "${DB_USER}" HostName: ""${DB_HOST}" " SID: "${DB_NAME}"."
        echo "`date` :Exiting Script Run..."
        exit 1
    fi
}

# run mysql function
runmysqls() {
    echo "`date` :Checking DB and table status..."

    mysql_db_statuscheck

    echo "`date` :DB status check completed"
    echo "`date` :Connecting To ${DB_USER}/******@${DB_NAME}";
    if [[ $DB_STATUS == "UP" ]]
    then
        # latest_migration will be an int
        EXEC_SQL='--execute="SELECT MAX(version) FROM migrations;"'
        latest_migration=`$SSH_PREFIX $MYSQL_CLIENT ${EXEC_SQL} ${DB_NAME} 2>&1`
        if [[ `echo "${latest_migration}" |cut -c 1-10` == "ERROR 1146" ]]; then
            echo "`date` :Running initial migration"
            latest_migration=0
        fi
        
        for file in `ls ./sql`; do
            file_migration_no=`echo "$file" |cut -c1-3`
            if [[ $latest_migration -lt $file_migration_no ]]; then
                echo "`date` :Executing migration $file_migration_no from file $file...";
                echo "`date` :__________________________________________";
                echo "`date` :SQL OUTPUT:";
                echo "`date` :__________________________________________";
                TAIL="-se '`cat ./sql/${file}`'"
                sqlout=`$SSH_PREFIX $MYSQL_CLIENT ${TAIL} 2>&1`
                if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then 
                    TAIL="-se 'INSERT INTO migrations (version) VALUES (${file_migration_no});'"
                    `$SSH_PREFIX $MYSQL_CLIENT ${TAIL}`
                else
                    echo ${sqlout}
                    exit 1
                fi
            fi
        done
    else
        echo "`date` :Either the DB is down or the exit status returned by
        the script shows ERROR."
        echo "`date` :Exiting ..."
        exit
    fi
}

# main function
Main() {
    echo "`date` :Starting sql auto run script."
    runmysqls
    echo "`date` :sql auto run script execution completed."
}
Main
```

When I run this against the remote database it runs fine. But when I run against the local instance, it just prints out the mysql help message.

I am printing the command to be run, `$ mysql --protocol=tcp -h localhost -u root --password=hotdog99 -e 'SELECT 1;' cooldb`

But if I copy and paste that from the script output into the terminal it runs fine!

If I set

```
EXEC_SQL=""
```

It drops me into the mysql shell, but as soon as `-e 'SELECT 1;'` or `--execute='SELECT 1;'` is inserted it goes back to printing the usage/help message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run it against a remote database, you're passing that `'SELECT 1;'` to `ssh`, which passes it to a shell as a command line argument, and that shell strips off the single quotes (`''`) as expected.

When you run it locally, you're merely dereferencing a variable. You're not passing it as an argument to a shell, so it gets expanded as is, meaning the argument you're passing to `mysql` is `'SELECT 1;'`, namely with the quotes.

You should use `sh -c "$cmd"` instead.

Demo:

```
$ ARG="'hello'"
$ cmd="echo ${ARG}"
$ echo $cmd
echo 'hello'
$ $cmd
'hello'
$ sh -c "$cmd"
hello
$ cmd="ssh 0 echo ${ARG}"
$ $cmd
hello
```